# Methods Not Found Symfony

Tags: php, symfony

i have the following code

```
<?php

namespace AppBundle\Controller;

use Sensio\Bundle\FrameworkExtraBundle\Configuration\Route;
use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
use AppBundle\Entity\Todo;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\TextareaType;

class ToDoController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Route("/todo", name="todo_list")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function listAction()
    {
        $todos = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Todo')->findAll();
        return $this->render('todo/index.html.twig', array(
            'todos' => $todos
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/todo/create", name="todo_create")
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function createAction(Request $request)
    {
        $todo = new Todo();

        $form = $this->createFormBuilder($todo)
            ->add('name', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('category', TextType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))
            ->add('description', TextareaType::class, array('attr' => array('class' => 'form-control', 'style' => 'margin-bottom:15px')))

            ;

            $form->handleRequest($request);

            if ($form->isSubmitted() && $form->isValid()) {
                die('Submitted');
            }

        return $this->render('todo/create.html.twig', array(
            'form' => $form->createView()
        ));
    }

    /**
     * @Route("todo/edit/{id}", name="todo_edit")
     * @param $id
     * @param Request $request
     * @return \Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response
     */
    public function editAction($id, Request $request)
    {
        return $this->render('todo/edit.html.twig');
    }

    /**
     * @Route("/todo/details/{id}", name="todo_details")
     */
    public function detailsAction($id)
    {
        return $this->render('todo/details.html.twig');
    }
}
```

The problem is that the mehods like **handleRequest() isSubmitted() isValid() createView() etc..** are not found. I don't have any idea why ? Can anyone help me ? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you do is

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($todo)
// ...
;

$form->handleRequest($request);
// ...
```

which is incorrect,
you need to do

```
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($todo)
// ...
->getForm()    
;
// ...
```

Your methods are not found because`createFormBuilder()` will return a `FormBuilder` object, the methods `handleRequest()` and the others are on the object `Form`

**Edit**

To remove your ide's warning about method definition being not found. you can do the following:

```
use Symfony\Component\Form\Form;

// ...

/** @var Form $form */
$form = $this->createFormBuilder($todo)
// ...
```

Note that it's 100% cosmetic, and the warnins will have no impact on code execution.

I don't know why your ide don't find the methods swhen the builder has > 1 fields. I can 100% reproduce this buggy behavior, but your code will work.

In order to fix those warnings you may consider [using form classes](http://symfony.com/doc/3.1/forms.html#creating-form-classes)

*Edit 2*

If you are using the Symfony Plugin for phpStorm there is a [similar issue](https://github.com/Haehnchen/idea-php-symfony2-plugin/issues/863) on their github

Comment: Okay, but how can i prevent this problem http://prikachi.com/images.php?images/225/9081225V.png

Comment: I don't get it, please describe your new problem (an edit on your question is fine)

Comment: The problem is that the 4th and  and 5th methods add() are not found and  the methods handleRequest. Please don't describe the problems, i want solution. I need to see the code working and take a notes.